# maven adding dependency on a shared package

Tags: java, maven, shared-libraries

I'm using Eclipse and Maven.

My current setup is 
- client (separate Eclipse and git project with it's own maven pom.xml) 
- server (separate Eclipse and git project with it's own maven pom.xml)

Both client and server are different projects in Eclipse and git.

However, there are some common Java packages shared between client and server. To avoid duplicates of the common package, I want to create a 3rd part, so my new setup would look like 
- client
- server 
- common

In Eclipse I can add the common project as a dependency to both my client and server and it will work. Same with git.

However, I'm not sure how I can define this dependency in my client and server pom.xml.

Comment: If you're having them share common packages and configurations, you would set the project up in a multi-module format, EX parent/child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a library out of your common part, then host it on your own maven repository and then you can add it as dependency to your server and client pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

you can add project as dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId> group-id-of-common-project</groupId>
      <artifactId> artifact-id-of-common-project</artifactId>
      <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```